# loop thru each section grab modal ID's and apply to modal component

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have the following sections & need to do the following 
Loop thru each section and grab the `data-target` value in each section.
 
Apply that `data-target` value to the modal `aria-labelledby` and `id` of the sibling

```
<section>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#example-one"> Modal Trigger </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true" id="" tabindex="-1">
            <p>modal content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#example-two"> Modal Trigger </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true" id="" tabindex="-1">
            <p>modal content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#example-three"> Modal Trigger </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true" id="" tabindex="-1">
            <p>modal content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply loop over each section- get the data-target of the a within the ul  li  and apply it to the 2 attributes (id and aria-labelled-by) of the modal within that section.

Also - not sure this implementation of the aria-labelled-by is correct-  you should not have the id of the element that is being labelled as the element you are labelling.

EDIT - updated to remove the "#" from the id - I did this by using .replace(/#/,'').

```js
$('section').each(function(){
  var modalId = $(this).find('a').attr('data-target').replace(/#/,'');
  console.log(modalId);
  var modal= $(this).find('.modal');
  modal.attr('id', modalId).attr('aria-labelledby', modalId)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#example-one"> Modal Trigger </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true" id="" tabindex="-1">
            <p>modal content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#example-two"> Modal Trigger </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true" id="" tabindex="-1">
            <p>modal content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#example-three"> Modal Trigger </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true" id="" tabindex="-1">
            <p>modal content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Incidentally - you don't actually need the data-target at all - just put that content into the a href attribute (and query that to get the contenfor the modal elements.

```js
$('section').each(function(){
  var modalId = $(this).find('a').attr('href').replace(/#/,'');
  console.log(modalId);
  var modal= $(this).find('.modal');
  modal.attr('id', modalId).attr('aria-labelledby', modalId)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#example-one" data-toggle="modal"> Modal Trigger </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true" id="" tabindex="-1">
            <p>modal content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#example-two" data-toggle="modal"> Modal Trigger </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true" id="" tabindex="-1">
            <p>modal content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#example-three" data-toggle="modal"> Modal Trigger </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true" id="" tabindex="-1">
            <p>modal content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @anotherbug - I have amended my answer to remove that character

Comment: Updated answer to simply replace the '#' - try that

Comment: are you loading jQuery in your page - this solution requires it (although you absolutely don't need jquery to do this action. Please post your console error to let me see what is failing.

Comment: `modal.component.ts:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`

Comment: This line" modal.component.ts:24" infers you are using angular and therefore should not be using jQuery to modify the dom - you should be using an angular solution to interpolate that id into the modal element on your ngRepeat.

Comment: im using typescript